# How to assign null for the object if object members have no value - automapper c#

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using automapper in c#.

```
class A 
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public B? Details { get; set; }
}

 class B 
 {
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
 } 

 class C
 {
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public int? DetailId { get; set; }
   public string? DetailName { get; set; }
 }
```

And in automapper I used like below:

```
CreateMap<C, A>()
.ForPath(o => o.Details.Id, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.DetailId))
.ForPath(o => o.Details.Name, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.DetailName))
.ReverseMap();
```

When I using like the above mapping, I get like output as

```
  "details ": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": ""
   }
```

I need to get `Details` value as null instead of an object type if it's members have no value. i.e) `DetailId` and `DetailName` have no value. How to get this?

```
  "details" : null
```

Comment: You can't with `ForPath`. Try [flattening](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can user Conditional Mapping

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
      {
         cfg.CreateMap<C, B>()
            .ForMember(o => o.Id, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.DetailId))
            .ForMember(o => o.Name, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.DetailName));

          cfg.CreateMap<C, A>()
             .ForMember(o => o.Details, b => b.MapFrom((c, a, obj, context) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.DetailName) ? context.Mapper.Map<B>(c) : null))
             .ReverseMap();
      });
```

Comment: I need detail property values as null.....i.e)  details: null instead of an object type.

Comment: @NivithaGopalakrishnan I have updated comment pls see bellow

Comment: @NivithaGopalakrishnan pls let me know  you need some additional details

Comment: If give like this means,  .ForMember(o => o.Details, b => b.Condition(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.DetailName))) , only null values is assigning. If have value means, object type is not returning.

Comment: Changed MapFrom it was my fault now it must work fine. But you must to declare mapping C=> B

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with an AutoMapper [after map action](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html).

Something like this:

```
CreateMap<C, A>()
    .ForPath(o => o.Details.Id, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.DetailId))
    .ForPath(o => o.Details.Name, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.DetailName))
    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
    {
        dest.Details = src.DetailId.HasValue && src.DetailName != null
            ? dest.Details
            : null;
    })
    .ReverseMap());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IValueResolver` interface to achieve what you require. Documentation: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Also there's a similar question: [Automapper Mapping Multiple Properties to Single Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205241/automapper-mapping-multiple-properties-to-single-property)

Configuration:

```
CreateMap<C, A>()
.ForMember(o => o.Details, b => b.MapFrom<DetailsValueResolver>())
.ReverseMap();
```

Implementation:

```
// Note: this does not cover ReverseMap() when you would try to convert A to C
public class DetailsValueResolver : IValueResolver<C, A, B>
{
    // Runs every time you map C to A
    public B Resolve(C source, A destination, B destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Covers cases where you can get null or empty DetailName, as well as null or zero DetailId
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.DetailName) && source.DetailId > 0)
        {
            return new B { Id = (int)source.DetailId, Name = source.DetailName };
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You also can omit explicitly setting strings and classes as nullable types with `?` as you do here:

```
public B? Details { get; set; }
public string? DetailName { get; set; }
```

Because `string` type and any class is `null` by default.