# How to write conditional mapping in Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have one model: Batch-parameters & two db Context objects NonFinBatchParams,PayProcBatchParams.

I need to map NonFinBatchParamsto Batch-parameters  & PayProcBatchParams to Batch-parameters. But it maps at a time one only.
I have to write automapper for mapping based on condition.
Here batchNumber is key and if batchNumber start with ("P") then map form NonFinBatchParams
otherwise PayProcBatchParams.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ctri.png)

Comment: In other words, you have to map a triplet (batchNumber,NonFinBatchParamsto,PayProcBatchParams) to Batch-parameters. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9205604/717732). That answer shows how to decide a value for Answer by inspecting several properties. If it solves your problem, please let us know so we can mark your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, also watch out for the last comment there from 1SaeedSalehi: > From automapper 8.0, ResolveUsing was replaced by MapFrom. [link](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing) - so you may need to change the method name in that snippet. Several years passed since it was written, things change sometimes :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl it is not working in my scenario.Please check Image for more clarification. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ctri.png

Comment: Have you tried doing [what has been shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9205604/717732)? Why isn't it working in our scenario? The image shows nothing except for a bunch of plain simple MapFroms. It doesn't show any attempt to use old ResolveUsing nor the new complex version of MapFrom.

Comment: Without code, it's hard to help. Source code of your source models, destination models and mapping configuration would be helpful.